# Video conferencing software that allows a participant to mute individual users

Tags: audio, conferencing

We have a few people working in an office and then a few more people working from home.

We would all like to video chat skype-style, but for the people in the office, everything that is said by someone in the same room "echos". The echo is because the hear it one time through the actual air, and then again through their headphones or speakers:

[image: Mute audio from this person since he is sitting right next to me and anything he says "echoes"]

Unsure of the best way to solve this problem, but one way seems to be to use an application that enables the user to mute audio from another participant. Then the people in the office could mute all audio from other people in the same room, thus removing the echo effect.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: what about teamviewer ?

Comment: Does teamviewer do video conferencing? I thought it was just screen-sharing? Do you have to fork over $750 per user to do this?

Comment: Yes It provides video conferencing, it provides a free version for non-commercial users, I use it with colleagues and friends, Not sure about the commercial version.

Comment: Did you find a tool to cover this? Since Hangout Toolbox is no longer supported in Google Hangouts, I'm looking for a new video conferencing app with local/individual mute functionality.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow have you since found such an app? I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In [Google+ Hangouts](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/) everyone can mute each other. When you mute people, they are muted for everyone, which is ideal for silent people who cause echo's.

Comment: This would mute all of the office people for the people who are not in the office who need to hear them, correct?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow I don't know what you mean. All people in a hangout can mute the microphone from any other person.

Comment: But if it also mutes it for everyone else, then if you mute the person sitting next to you, then the people not in the room cannot hear that person at all, correct?

Comment: Uhm, what do you mean with "next to you"? If he is physically next to you he can be heard through your own microphone...

Comment: That's one of the complexities of the situation. I was able to solve that problem by getting a conference call mic and then muting everyone else who is in the office's mic.